# Can a right mouse click be used to shut down Ubuntu? Version 16.04 LTS

Tags: shutdown

This is a curiosity question; Is there a way to enable a right mouse click on the desktop to display "Shut Down" as a choice?

I checked the Unity Tweak tool and did not see anything.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add shutdown option to right click context menu. With the right tool , it is possible to do so.

First, open up a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions
```

This will install **Nautilus-Actions Configuration Tool**, which I mean by "right tool" thus making it essential in order to modify right click.

Once the installation has finished, launch `nautilus-actions-config-tool`.

Define a new action by click top left icon. Then:

- Fill the desired name on Context lable field, "shut down" for example.
- Also make sure you tick **Display item in location context menu**, so if you right click on blank space (e.g. desktop). You also get the defined action.

Click <kbd>Command</kbd> tab, type `/sbin/poweroff` on Path field. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save the change. Now "Shut Down" should appear as option on right click.

[image: Shutdown option]